# Split categorical column to multiple columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

[image: Data frame screenshot]

and I want to convert it to this format:

[image]

I have succeed that with `get_dummies` but i am trying to do the same with defining a function like:

```
def func():
    if per_country['confirmed']=='confirmed':
        return per_country['cases']
    else:
        return 0

per_country['virus_confirmed']=per_country['type'].apply(func)
```

The `per_country` dataframe is the first screenshot.

But i am getting this error:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `cases` column in your original data frame, so your function would fail even if it were written correctly.

Comment: You have the error : 

`TypeError : func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 given` 

When you run `apply` (last line), with `func` as argument, that means that you give to `func` one argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `apply`, it's implicitly passing each record of `per_country['type']` to func. If you want to do this more simply and clearer, you can use a lambda function.

```
per_country['virus_confirmed'] = per_country.apply(lambda x: x['cases'] if x['type']=="confirmed" else 0, axis=1)
```

EDIT:
For the apply function, note that you're applying it to a series in the DataFrame. This means that x is each record from that column and that you don't need to specify the axis. I applied it to the whole DataFrame, which means I do need to specify the axis. With axis=1, x in my lambda function stands in for each row of the dataframe.

Lastly, I also forgot to mention that you can get this done even quicker with the dummy variables by doing:

```
per_country['virus_confirmed'] = per_country['cases']*per_country['confirmed']
```

Because columns that aren't confirmed are marked with a 0, it will give you the same result, but in a vectorized manner. If you're working with a Covid-19 dataset, I don't think you'll notice a huge difference, but it's a good habit to look for opportunities to vectorize.

Answer (score 0):

`func` is a function that takes 0 parameters. `apply` passes data to the first parameter of the function. This obviously fails because `func` does not accept any parameters.

You seem confused about the basics of Python scoping. You can consult [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules#292502) for an introduction.

In short, you are trying to write a function that is applied *to each row* of the data frame. Therefore your function `func` must accept a row as its parameter.

```py
# Each row will be passed as the "x" parameter

def func(x):
    if x['confirmed'] == 'confirmed':
        return x['cases']
    else:
        return 0

# axis=1 is required to apply the function row-wise

per_country['virus_confirmed'] = per_country.apply(func, axis=1)
```

That said, the function you're asking about doesn't seem related to the data you're showing, so this whole question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Just on another note : A one hot encoding is appropriate for categorical data where no relationship exists between categories. It involves representing each categorical variable with a binary vector that has one element for each unique label and marking the class label with a 1 and all other elements 0 which is the one you are trying. The scikit-learn library provides the OneHotEncoder to automatically one hot encode one or more variables.